# CVXPY throws SolverError

Tags: python, convex-optimization, cvxopt, cvxpy

When using CVXPY, I frequently get "SolverError". Their [doc](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/faq/index.html#what-do-i-do-if-i-get-a-solvererror-exception) just says this is caused by numerical issues, but no further information is given about how to avoid them.

The following code snippet is an example, the problem is trivial, but the ['CVXOPT'](http://www.cvxpy.org/en/latest/tutorial/advanced/) solver just throws "SolverError". It is true that if we change the solver to another one, like 'ECOS', the problem will be solved as expected. But the point is, 'CVXOPT' should in principle solve this trivial problem and it really baffles me why it doesn't work.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cv
np.random.seed(0)
temp = np.random.rand(5)
T = 2
x = cv.Variable(T)
u = cv.Variable(2, T)
pbs = []
for t in range(T):
    cost = cv.sum_squares(x[t]-temp[t])
    constr = [x[t] == u[0,t]+u[1,t],]
    pbs.append(cv.Problem(cv.Minimize(cost), constr))
prob = sum(pbs)
prob.solve(solver='CVXOPT')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `prob.solve(solver='CVXOPT', kktsolver=cv.ROBUST_KKTSOLVER)` to make the optimisation process more robust.